# Minecraft wont launch (framebuffer object)

Tags: drivers, java, minecraft

Good evening,

as the title says there is a small issue with minecraft, due to other problems I got to use an pretty old computer which should easily run minecraft.

I also got the crash report according to that.

> ---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
>   // This doesn't make any sense!
>
> Time: 18.08.19 19:09 Description: Initializing game
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver does not appear to support
>   framebuffer objects   at
>   com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GLX.init(SourceFile:438)  at
>   cyc.au(SourceFile:482)    at cyc.b(SourceFile:394)    at
>   net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:155)
>
> A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known
>
> ### details is as follows:
>
> -- Head -- Thread: Client thread Stacktrace:  at com.mojang.blaze3d.platform.GLX.init(SourceFile:438)     at
>   cyc.au(SourceFile:482)
>
> -- Initialization -- Details: Stacktrace:     at cyc.b(SourceFile:394)    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:155)
>
> -- System Details -- Details:     Minecraft Version: 1.14.4   Minecraft Version ID: 1.14.4    Operating System: Windows 7 (amd64) version 6.1
>     Java Version: 1.8.0_51, Oracle Corporation  Java VM Version: Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation     Memory:
>   1700499696 bytes (1621 MB) / 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB) up to
>   2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)    CPUs: 2     JVM Flags: 9 total;
>   -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump
>   -Xss1M -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M  Launched Version: 1.14.4    LWJGL: 3.2.2 build 10   OpenGL: Intel Bear Lake B GL version 1.4.0 - Build 8.14.10.1930, Intel  GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing. Using GL 1.3 texture combiners. Using framebuffer
>   objects because   Using VBOs: Yes     Is Modded: Probably not. Jar
>   signature remains and client brand is untouched.  Type: Client
>   (map_client.txt)  Resource Packs:     Current Language: ~~ERROR~~
>   NullPointerException: null    CPU:

I know that

> the driver doesn't support the framebuffer objects

but I don't know how I should solve the problem.

Thanks, Steven Vetter

Answer (score 0):

The decider is

> OpenGL: Intel Bear Lake B GL version 1.4.0

That GPU is not capable of running Minecraft. The minimum OpenGL required is 4.4 according to [Mojang - Minecraft: Java Edition system requirements](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements)

This seems an odd minimum requirement, usually the minimum is 2.1 [which was a base standard for many years & is in fact the only version still usable on Macs, to most intents & purposes.]
The point, however is moot if you can only support OGL 1.4.

If that's a desktop machine, pretty much any new graphics card would be expected to support OpenGL 4.4, even a really really cheap $£€20 card.